# Display all items in wishlist on 1.6

Tags: magento

On the customers side the wishlist only displays 3 products, is there a way to display all of their products in their wishlist like in the admin? We are using Magento 1.6.

Answer (score 3):

I **assume** you're referring to the sidebar wishlist, as the wishlist on the customer dashboard doesn't appear to have a limit.

On line 46 of `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Sidebar.php` you'll see the following line:

```
->setPageSize(3)
```

If you want to remove the limit entirely, comment out this line.  Otherwise change the number on this line to whatever you'd like the new limit to be.

**Note:** I strongly recommend not changing the core file if you intend upgrading Magento in future.  You can override the core version of the block by copying it to `app/code/local/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Sidebar.php`.  Another, more future-proof alternative would be to create a block that inherits from this class in a custom extension and alter the layout files accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that would work but it would also change the amount of items in the sidebar, we only wanted to change the amount on the wishlist page. Apparently the wishlist page is inherent to the side bar. This link we found (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/218466/#t338583) has a hack to that to display all items on the page but only 3 in the sidebar.

Comment: Care to share your link?  The Wishlist block appears to be independent of the Sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Go to wishlist/sidebar.phtml and add 'setPageSize(20)'

```
<?php foreach ($this->getWishlistItems()->setPageSize(20) as $_item): ?>
```